# What is the meaning of this phrase? "at the expense of being wrong"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Below is the context the phrase is used.

We are looking to assemble a small elite team. We want people who value being right, but not ***at the expense of being wrong***.

Thanks

Comment: It would be assumed that "being wrong" would have negative consequences, and you are trying to avoid that. But your context is confusing, because you are saying such person could be right and wrong.

Comment: Here is the whole paragraph.  
 http://comma.ai/hiring.html

Comment: The relevant part should be added to your question, and add the link as a source.

Comment: We are looking to assemble a small elite team. We want people who value being right, but not at the expense of being wrong. Roles we are hiring for include Lead Phone App Engineer (hired), Controls Engineer (hired), Software Engineer, Electrical Engineer (hired), Computer Vision Engineer, and Machine Learning Researcher.   Here is the link http://comma.ai/hiring.html

Answer (score 2):

As user208959 linked to, the text is from a job posting ad:

> We are looking to assemble a small elite team. We want people who
>   value being right, but not at the expense of being wrong.

*[at the expense of](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/at-the-expense-of)* is an idiomatic expression in English, meaning that doing the first thing harms the second thing. For example:

> She acquired power **at the expense of** friendships.
>
> He argues that the tax cut will benefit the rich **at the expense of** the poor.
>
> She's focusing on math **at the expense of** her other subjects.

In the example you've provided, I agree it is a confusing example of the usage of the expression. I believe the person posting the ad is trying to say that they want the best people for the job - people who do the job right, but not so sure they are right that they are unwilling who seek advice or listen to other people if they happen to be wrong. In other words, they are looking for open minded people who, presumably, work well in a team.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mike. It was really helpful for me to understand. Have a good day~ ^^

Comment: If you found @mike's answer useful, it would be courteous to *accept* it and, since you have the reputation, *upvote* it. That's how this community is supposed to work.